# iPhone application with dual interface and AppStore

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

I have question about application with dual interface on iPhone (different interfaces choosen in settings). Default interface can be pretty for standard Apple users, second interface can be practical. Is it possible to submit app like this on AppStore ?

-- 
Regards 
Adam

Answer (score 1):

Why not? :) If you not use anything that is against the guidelines, it is possible to submit.